# Client side rendering using React.render omits onerror attribute of image tag

Tags: javascript, node.js, html, reactjs, pug

I have a common jade to render on server and sometimes on client side as well. One thing I want to achieve is, onerror of image load, try replacing its *src*.

Here is the sample jade.

```
img.smart-img(src="#{thumb}" data-alt-img="#{alt-thumb}" data-default-img="#{default-img}" onerror='loadAltImgs(this);')
```

I am running Grunt task to convert this jade to javascript template let's say imageRender.template.js. I am using React only for rendering perspective. The above sample renders perfectly when rendered on server side.

When I render it on client side as:

```
React.render(imageRender, {
  thumb: 'thumb.jpg',
  'alt-thumb': 'alt-thumb.jpg',
  'default-thumb': 'defalt-thumb.jpg'
});
```

DOM renders image with src and data attributes, but it doesn't contain onerror handler for this. Can someone please help me with this?

Thanks.

Comment: `onerror` is not a native (or global like data-*) attribute for the `img` tag?

Comment: It is a native event handler to be precise.